# CacheStorage in Rails PWA always empty. In service-worker.js cache.addAll doesn't seem to cache anything

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

After searching for days for some kind of solution, I have come up empty. My service-worker gets registered, installs, and activates without a problem, but the cache.addAll seems to fail silently.

I am using a controller to serve the service-worker and manifest.json as erb views. I am solely using webpacker and not the asset pipeline, which rules out some of the common gems used for this sort of thing.

Here is my service-worker.js.erb:

```
const expectedCaches = ['static-v2'];

function onInstall(event) {
    console.log('[Serviceworker]', "Installing!", event);
    event.waitUntil(
    caches.open("static-v2")
        .then(function(cache) {
            return cache.addAll([
                '/offline.html',
                '<%= asset_pack_path 'application.js' %>',
                '<%= asset_pack_path 'media/images/Convertable.png' %>',
                '<%= root_path %>',

            ])
            .then(function(e){ 
                console.log(e);
            })
            .catch(function(e){
                console.log(e.message);
            });
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err.message);
    })
  );
}

function onActivate(event) {
  console.log('[Serviceworker]', "Activating!", event);
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames) {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.filter(function(cacheName) {
          // Return true if you want to remove this cache,
          // but remember that caches are shared across
          // the whole origin
          return expectedCaches.includes(cacheName);
        }).map(function(cacheName) {
          return caches.delete(cacheName);
        })
      );
    })
  );
}


function onFetch(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    // try to return untouched request from network first
    fetch(event.request).catch(function() {
      // if it fails, try to return request from the cache
      return caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
        if (response) {
          return response;
        }
        // if not found in cache, return default offline content for navigate requests
        if (event.request.mode === 'navigate' ||
          (event.request.method === 'GET' && event.request.headers.get('accept').includes('text/html'))) {
          console.log('[Serviceworker]', "Fetching offline content", event);
          return caches.match('/offline.html');
        }
      })
    })
  );
}

self.addEventListener('install', onInstall);
self.addEventListener('activate', onActivate);
self.addEventListener('fetch', onFetch);
```

And my manifest.json.erb

```
{
  "short_name": "My APP",
  "name": "My APP for Everyone!",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "<%= asset_pack_path 'media/images/Convertable.png' %>",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "<%= asset_pack_path 'media/images/Convertable.png' %>",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "<%= root_path %>",
  "background_color": "#fff",
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "<%= root_path %>",
  "theme_color": "#000"
}
```

Like I said, it registers and installs just fine, but when I use chrome dev tools to enter offline mode, it fails to load anything that was supposed to be cached and I get this in the console:

```
The FetchEvent for "http://localhost:3000/offline.html" resulted in a network error response: an object that was not a Response was passed to respondWith().
Promise.then (async)
onFetch @ service-worker.js:47
```

which is because undefined is returned as the response since nothing is found in the cache. Debugging into the fetch event handler I find that the CacheStorage object is indeed empty. Looking in the application tab of chrome dev tools I can't find anything caches, although I am not quite sure which cache it should end up in (several are listed).

I get the same result in Firefox as well. I am hoping I missed something simple that someone can point out to me, or at least someone to get me down the right path. I will try to be very responsive to any requests for additional information.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like in `onActivate` event handler you are deleting the items from the Cache Storage which you have added previously in `onInstall` event.

You should delete the caches which are not in `expectedCaches` array (now you are doing opposite :-)). So try to change the condition to `return !expectedCaches.includes(cacheName);` (add exclamation mark), which will filter the old caches only.

Comment: *facepalm* ... Thank you so much for being my second pair of eyes when mine have failed me. You really have made my day and I am sorry I took up your time with such a stupid mistake!

Comment: You are very welcome! Good luck with your PWA! Thank you!